# How to remove the logic from ViewModel and move to Repository

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have this piece of code which is checking if it is close to the start time and if no repeats until it is started
I want to have less logic in ViewModel how can I refactor this piece of code?

```
    uiScope.launch {
      when (val unixTimeMillisecond = serverTimeFetcher.fetchUnixTime()) {
        is Response.Success<Long> -> {
          var title = "Play"
          val startTimeMillis = FULL_DATE_FORMAT.parse(startTime).time
          if (startTimeMillis > unixTimeMillisecond.data) {
            val difference = startTimeMillis - unixTimeMillisecond.data
            title = DURATION_FORMAT.format(Duration.millis(difference))
            liveEventActionTitleMutableData.postValue(title)
            delay(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            checkLiveEventStatus(startTime)
          } else {
            liveEventActionTitleMutableData.postValue(title)
          }

        }
        is Response.Failure -> errorMessageMutableData.postValue(unixTimeMillisecond.message)
      }
    }
  }



  override suspend fun fetchUnixTime(): Response<Long> {
    var timeDifference = apiPreferences.getLong("PREF_TIME_DIFFERENCE", -1)
    val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return if (timeDifference == -1L) {
      when (val serverTimeResult = fetchServerTime()) {
        is Response.Success<ServerTime> -> {
          val epochMillis = serverTimeResult.data.epochMillis
          timeDifference = currentTimeMillis - epochMillis
          apiPreferences.edit().putLong("PREF_TIME_DIFFERENCE", timeDifference).apply()
          (Response.Success((epochMillis)))
        }
        else -> Response.Failure("error message")
      }
    } else {
      val epochMillis = currentTimeMillis - timeDifference
      Response.Success(epochMillis)
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your repository code.

Comment: I have updated it, I think we need to have a separate method in repository